# How to store a grid of values in a PostGIS database such that it can be contoured by GeoServer?

Tags: postgis, contour, geoserver

I'm planning to use GeoServer with a PostGIS database to provide contours over a Web Mapping Service.

I have a simple lat-long grid of values which I want to store in the database and have contoured. Whilst the GeoServer user manual implies that it is possible in this example...

https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld/extensions/rendering-transform.html#contour-extraction

...it does not talk about what format the data should be in. Please can anyone suggest a suitable PostGIS database schema I can use that GeoServer will understand and be able to contour? Preferably one which will work with the GeoServer example from the link above.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi Tim, welcome to Stack Overflow. In which format do you have your geometries now? Can you add a sample in your question? There are many ways to import spatial data into PostgreSQL:)

Comment: Consider not storing the DEM in PostGIS, but the contours themselves as geometries; use specific tools like the mighty GDAL to extract and import them; querying of raster data from DB to then process it on-the-fly will add *significant* overhead to your application.

Comment: Thanks for response @JimJones, currently the data is stored in a Java class where the data values are stored in a 2D array. The class also stores a lat-lon bounding box, which defines the spatial area that the values cover. The values are assumed to be equal distances apart, e.g. increments of 0.001 lat and long degrees. I'm still in the design stage with the database, so I'm very flexible as to how the data from that Java class is put into PostGIS.

Comment: Thanks for the warning @ThingumaBob. The reason why I was interested in having GeoServer perform the contouring was that I wanted users to be able to adjust the thresholds for the contours without having to re-generate the data - generating the data could take many hours. The grids are typically 0.01 degrees latitude by 0.01 longitude, with 0.00001 degree steps, i.e. 1,000,000 data points. Do you think that GeoServer would struggle to contour that amount of data on-the-fly?

Comment: @Tim have you considered creating this grid inside the database instead of importing it? Sometime ago I found a function in another SO Community that creates a grid based on cell size and starting point - I also had a solution for a grid of hexagons. Let me know if it interests you.

Comment: GeoServer is expecting a raster datasource there so usually a GeoTiff or similar. You could store a raster in PostGIS but a file is probably easier

Comment: @JimJones the grid is output by some existing code, so the data already exists in the Java. I guess my question is more about how to put that data in the PostGIS database so that GeoServer can efficiently contour it. Have you tried contouring the data stored by the functions you mentioned?

Comment: Thanks @IanTurton. That sounds like what I'm looking for. The only sticking point now might be the one made by ThingumaBob who was concerned that GeoServer might not be able to do the contouring fast enough. I guess the only surefire way to find out is to try it, so I'll give it ago over the next couple of days and post my findings.

Comment: Sounds like detailed contours would only be required when zoomed in, use scale dependant styling to control when it applies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your data is already in a Java program, I would dive into [GeoTools](https://geotools.org) which is the underlying library that [GeoServer](https://geoserver.org) uses to do the actual work.

Looking at [ContourProcess](https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/master/modules/unsupported/process-raster/src/main/java/org/geotools/process/raster/ContourProcess.java) what you actually need is a [GridCoverage2D](https://docs.geotools.org/latest/javadocs/org/geotools/coverage/grid/GridCoverage2D.html) which is basic access to grid data values backed by a two-dimensional rendered image. Each band in an image is represented as a sample dimension.

So you'd want to take your data array and do something like this:

```
WritableRaster raster2 = RasterFactory.createBandedRaster(java.awt.image.DataBuffer.TYPE_INT, w,
    h, 1, null);
for (int i = 0; i < w; i++) {//width...
     for (int j = 0; j < h; j++) {
         raster2.setSample(i, j, 0, myData[i*w+j]);
     }
}
GridCoverageFactory gcf = new GridCoverageFactory();
// Here I'm using OSGB as I live in the UK you would be using something else
CoordinateReferenceSystem crs = CRS.decode("EPSG:27700");
// Position of Lower Left Corner of grid
int llx = 500000;
int lly = 105000;
// Pixel size in projection units
int resolution = 10;
ReferencedEnvelope referencedEnvelope = new ReferencedEnvelope(llx, llx + (w * resolution), lly, lly + (h * resolution),
    crs);
GridCoverage2D gc = gcf.create("name", raster2, referencedEnvelope);
```

You can either then write it out as a GeoTiff or wrap all the above up into [a new Process](https://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/tutorial/process.html) which returns contours.

Comment: Great, this looks like it could be the solution I'm looking for. I'll have a bit of a play and let you know how I get on.

Answer (score 0):

So I had a play and can confirm that the code by @IanTurton works like a charm. Here is my final code, based on his with the main differences being that I'm using a lat/long coordinate reference system and I've included some code to write the raster out as a GeoTIFF...

```
import java.awt.image.WritableRaster;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.imageio.stream.ImageOutputStream;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.media.jai.RasterFactory;

import org.geotools.coverage.grid.GridCoverage2D;
import org.geotools.coverage.grid.GridCoverageFactory;
import org.geotools.geometry.jts.ReferencedEnvelope;
import org.geotools.referencing.CRS;
import org.geotools.referencing.crs.DefaultGeographicCRS;
import org.geotools.gce.geotiff.GeoTiffFormat;
import org.geotools.gce.geotiff.GeoTiffWriter;
import org.opengis.parameter.ParameterValue;
import org.opengis.referencing.FactoryException;
import org.opengis.referencing.NoSuchAuthorityCodeException;
import org.opengis.referencing.crs.CoordinateReferenceSystem;

public class GridToGeoTiff {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchAuthorityCodeException, FactoryException, IllegalArgumentException, IndexOutOfBoundsException, IOException {

        // Define the data grid
        double[][] myGrid = {
                { 0.0, 0.2, 0.6, 0.3 },
                { 0.1, 1.1, 0.8, 0.7 },
                { 1.1, 2.6, 3.4, 0.3 },
                { 0.3, 0.9, 0.6, 0.1 }
        };

        int w = myGrid.length;
        int h = myGrid[0].length;

        // Position of Lower Left Corner of grid
        double southBound = 51.5074; // degrees latitude
        double westBound = 0.1278; // degrees latitude
        double resolution = 0.001; // degrees lat/long

        // Convert to a Raster
        WritableRaster raster2 = RasterFactory.createBandedRaster(java.awt.image.DataBuffer.TYPE_INT, w, h, h, null);
            for (int i = 0; i < w; i++) {
                 for (int j = 0; j < h; j++) {
                      raster2.setSample(i, j, 0, myGrid[j][i]);
                 }
            }

            // Create a GeoTools 2D grid referenced in lat/long 
            GridCoverageFactory gcf = new GridCoverageFactory();
            CoordinateReferenceSystem crs = DefaultGeographicCRS.WGS84;
            ReferencedEnvelope referencedEnvelope = new ReferencedEnvelope(
                westBound, westBound + (w * resolution), southBound, southBound + (h * resolution), crs
            );
            GridCoverage2D gc = gcf.create("my-grid", raster2, referencedEnvelope);

            // Write out to a GeoTIFF file
            final File geotiff = new File("my-grid.tif");
            final ImageOutputStream imageOutStream = ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(geotiff);
            GeoTiffWriter writer = new GeoTiffWriter(imageOutStream);
            final ParameterValue<Boolean> tfw = GeoTiffFormat.WRITE_TFW.createValue();
            tfw.setValue(true);
            writer.write(gc, null);
            writer.dispose();
    }
}
```

I'm using the following Maven dependencies...

- **org.geotools** 22.2: gt-main, gt-coverage, gt-referencing, gt-geometry, gt-geotiff
- **org.opengis** 2.2.0: geoapi
- **org.locationtech.jts** 1.16.1: jts-core
- **javax.media.jai** 1.1.3: com.springsource.javax.media.jai.core

...from the Boundless and OSGeo repositories.

Having used this code to create a GeoTIFF file, I could then use it to set up a store in GeoServer and then publish it. I adapted the SLD in GeoServer's [contouring example](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld/extensions/rendering-transform.html#contour-extraction) (literally just changed the names and contouring thresholds) to create a style, which I then applied to the published GeoTIFF data, et voilà contours on a map!

But... my data is not static and I will be producing many different grids, so this file based approach is going to be a little bit clunky. Therefore I'm going to look into GeoServer's [ImageMosaic plugin](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/tutorials/imagemosaic_timeseries/imagemosaic_timeseries.html) as a way of getting the contours straight from the database. However, it seems that this is not a popular option, and might not be production ready (according to [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/62125)), so I may end up contouring the data myself and storing it as vectors after all. If anyone has further thoughts on this I'd love to hear them.

Thanks for all your help everyone!